# Use of incomplete types in templates

Tags: c++, templates, incomplete-type

Is it legal to use an incomplete type in a template if the type is complete when the template is instantiated?

As below

```
#include <iostream>

struct bar;

template <typename T>
struct foo {

    foo(bar* b) : b(b) {
    }
    
     void frobnicate() {
          b->frobnicate();
     }

     T val_;
     bar* b;
};

struct bar {
     void frobnicate() {
          std::cout << "foo\n";
     }
};

int main() {
    bar b;
    foo<int> f(&b);
    f.frobnicate();
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio compiles the above without complaining. GCC issues the warning `invalid use of incomplete type 'struct bar'` but compiles. Clang errors out with `member access into incomplete type 'bar'`.

Comment: You could change the template to `template <typename T, typename BAR>` and then have `BAR` instead of `bar` in the template, and in `main` use `foo<int, bar> f(&b);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clang is correct in reporting an error (as opposed to a warning or being silent about it), though MSVC's and GCC's behavior are also consistent with the standard. See @HolyBlackCat's answer for details on that.

The code you posted is ill-formed NDR. However, what you want to do is feasible.

You can defer the definition of template member functions the same way you would for a non-template class. Much like non-template classes, as long as these definitions requiring `bar` to be a complete type happen only once `bar` is complete, everything is fine.

The only hiccup is that you need to explicitly mark the method as inline  to avoid ODR violations in multi-TU programs, since the definition will almost certainly be in a header.

```
#include <iostream>

struct bar;

template <typename T>
struct foo {

    foo(bar* b) : b(b) {
    }
    
    inline void frobnicate();

    T val_;
    bar* b;
};

struct bar {
     void frobnicate() {
          std::cout << "foo\n";
     }
};

template <typename T>
void foo<T>::frobnicate() {
     b->frobnicate();
}

int main() {
    bar b;
    foo<int> f(&b);
    f.frobnicate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is ill-formed NDR rather than ill-formed, so all compilers are correct. (But yes, Clang is more correct.)

Comment: NDR, as it is not always (in general case) possible to detect such errors.

Comment: So NDR is kind of like the "undefined behavior" of compile time?

Comment: @jwezorek kinda-sorta. I can definitely see how you could see similarities. But there's a big difference between "being allowed to assume something will never happen" (UB) and "acknowledging that certain things can't be detected in all scenarios" (NDR)

Answer (score 5):

The code is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

> #### [`[temp.res.general]/6.4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.4)
>
> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation.
>
> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
> ...
> — a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, ...

---

If you absolutely can't define `bar` before the template, there is a workaround: you can introduce an artifical dependency on the template parameter.

```
template <typename T, typename, typename...>
struct dependent_type {using type = T;};
template <typename T, typename P0, typename ...P>
using dependent_type_t = typename dependent_type<T, P0, P...>::type;
```

Then use `dependent_type_t<bar, T>` instead of `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customise a template using a forward declaration as a temlpate argument, you can do this (wihtout warnings or errors):

```
template <typename T, typename = T>
class print_name;
```

so when you do a partial specialization, you use the second, unspecialized template parameter for your calls:

```
struct john;

template <typename T>
class print_name<john, T>
{
public:
    void operator()(const T& f) const
    {
        std::cout << f.name << std::endl;
    }
};
```

In this context `T` is not incomplete. But when you instantiate `print_name<john>`, SFINAE will kick.

Here is a full example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename = T>
class print_name;

struct john;

template <typename T>
class print_name<john, T>
{
public:
    void operator()(const T& f) const
    {
        std::cout << f.name << std::endl;
    }
};

struct slim;

template <typename T>
class print_name<slim, T>
{
public:
    void operator()(const T& f) const
    {
        std::cout << f.myName << std::endl;
    }
};


#include <string>

struct john
{
    std::string name;
};

struct slim
{
    std::string myName;
};

int main()
{
    print_name<john>{}(john{"John Cena"});
    print_name<slim>{}(slim{"Slim Shady"});
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/czcGo5aaG

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to get around this problem is to make `bar` a dependent type like this:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

struct bar;

template<typename T, std::same_as<bar> Bar = bar>
struct foo {
    foo(Bar* b): b(b) {}
    
    void frobnicate()
    { b->frobnicate(); }

    T val_;
    Bar* b;
};

struct bar {
    void frobnicate()
    { std::cout << "foo\n"; }
};

int main() {
    bar b;
    foo<int> f(&b);
    f.frobnicate();
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/vcazv7Mn9)