# Use of incomplete template types in templates

Tags: c++, templates

This is follow up to [a question I asked a few weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69712496/use-of-incomplete-types-in-templates) in which the answer was that it is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, to use a type in a template that is only complete at the time of the template's instantiation but not at the time of its definition.

My follow up question is is this still true in the case in which the incomplete type is itself dependent on the template parameter? because it seems that it is not. The following compiles in all the compilers on Godbolt, even though `foo::do_stuff()` is using `foo_wrapper::value()` given only a forward declaration that a class template `foo_wrapper` will eventually exist.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class foo_wrapper;

template<typename T>
class foo {
    foo_wrapper<T>& parent_;
public:
    foo(foo_wrapper<T>& wrapped) : parent_(wrapped)
    {}

    void do_stuff() {
        std::cout << "do stuff " << parent_.value() << "\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
class foo_wrapper {
    foo<T> foo_;
    T value_;
public:

    foo_wrapper(T n) :
        foo_(*this),
        value_(n)
    {}

    void do_stuff() {
        foo_.do_stuff();
    }

    T value() const {
        return value_;
    }

};

int main()
{
    foo_wrapper<int> fw(42);
    fw.do_stuff();
}
```

Comment: Your code here is different, because you access a templated class `foo_wrapper`. The linked answer gives "a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter". In this case here, the code depends on the template parameter.

Comment: In your code, template `foo` is able to use the as-yet-defined `foo_wrapper` because *you've only used references*.  Though specific details of the type aren't yet known, the compiler knows the references will be pointers, and thus what their size will be for passing and storage.  That's enough for `foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is legal.

The rule of thumb is that everything that depends on template parameters is checked when the template is instantiated. Everything else is either checked when the template is first seen, **or** when it's instantiated (e.g. MSVC tends to check everything late, and Clang tends to do it as early as possible).